# Get Element from XDocument & Edit Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

```
<GetPromotionByIdResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" MajorVersion="2" xmlns="http://fake.com/services">
    <Header>
        <Response ResponseCode="OK">
            <RequestID>1</RequestID>
        </Response>
    </Header>
    <Promotion PromotionId="5200" EffectiveDate="2014-10-10T00:00:00" ExpirationDate="2014-11-16T23:59:00" PromotionStatus="Active" PromotionTypeName="DefaultPromotion">
        <Description TypeCode="Long" Culture="en-AU">Promotion Description</Description>
    </Promotion>
</GetPromotionByIdResponse>
```

Im trying to extract this

```
<Promotion PromotionId="5200" EffectiveDate="2014-10-10T00:00:00" ExpirationDate="2014-11-16T23:59:00" PromotionStatus="Active" PromotionTypeName="DefaultPromotion">
        <Description TypeCode="Long" Culture="en-AU">Promotion Description</Description>
    </Promotion>
```

and convert the PromotionId="5200" to PromotionId="XXX"

I can extract the < Promotion > element with the below code but cant work out how to change the attribute

```
XNamespace xmlResponseNamespace = xmlPromotionResponse.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

        XmlNamespaceManager nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        nsm.AddNamespace("def", xmlResponseNamespace.ToString());

        XElement xmlPromotionElement =
            xmlPromotionResponse
            .Descendants().SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name.LocalName == "Promotion");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
XNamespace ns = "http://fake.com/services";
XElement xmlPromotionElement = xmlPromotionResponse.Descendants(ns+"Promotion")
                                                   .SingleOrDefault();
xmlPromotionElement.Attribute("PromotionId").Value = "XXX";
```

Use simple `XNamespace` + local-name to reference an element in namespace. Then you can use `.Attribute()` method to get `XAttribute` from an `XElement` and change the attribute's value.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks so much.

I like using the XNamespace better than the namespacemanager...so much less code.

Comment: `XmlNamespaceManager` used if you're using XPath to query the XML (in this case we use LINQ, not XPath). Your original code should even work if you remove the 2 line of codes involving `XmlNamespaceManager`

Answer (score 0):

Try this : It returns the value of all attributes in *Promotion* Tag.

```
 XNamespace ns1 = XNamespace.Get("http://fake.com/services");
 var readPromotion = from a in xx.Descendants(ns1 + "Promotion")
                            select new
                            {
                                PromotionID = (string)a.Attribute("PromotionId"),
                                EffectiveDate = (string)a.Attribute("EffectiveDate"),
                                ExpirationDate = (string)a.Attribute("ExpirationDate"),
                                PromotionStatus = (string)a.Attribute("PromotionStatus"),
                                PromotionTypeName = (string)a.Attribute("PromotionTypeName"),
                                Description = (string)a.Value

                            };

        foreach (var read in readPromotion)
        {
            // Read values
        }
```